# In python how can I get the date and time of my local server?

Tags: python, server, python-datetime

I am aware of the datetime library. However, on top of knowing the date and time of the world, I also need to know the date and time of the local server my application will be running on. The reason for this is because my local server is not connected to the internet so it may have a different date and time and I want to be able to detect it if that's the case. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `datetime` package, as you refer to, you can get the current *local* time e.g. by

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)
```

This *is* the local time on the machine. Python does not reach out to the world over the internet to ask what time it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I may have phrased it wrong. Even if python gets the time from the local machine, the time is still set by default via internet. However, if I need the time for a local server that my machine is connected to. It just hit me that I may need to set up a socket to receive the information from the server.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the `time` module which has a `localtime` method. However this just reformats `time`.

```
import time
localTime = time.localtime()
print (localTime)
```